# Disable all inbound rules in Windows server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, windows-firewall

I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 and I need to disable all of the inbound rules. Is there any kind of powershell script to disable the rules all at once and start from a blank canvas?

I'm running multiple servers that are not in a domain and it takes too much time to disable them one by one.

Comment: Something along the lines of: `Show-NetFirewallRule | where {$_.enabled -eq 'true' -AND $_.direction -eq 'inbound'} | Disable-NetFirewallRule`. Quite basic commands that shouldn't be too hard to come up with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Lenniey to my problem:

```
Show-NetFirewallRule | where {$_.enabled -eq 'true' -AND $_.direction -eq 'inbound'} | Disable-NetFirewallRule.
```